# How do you say "OpSec" in Japanese?

Tags: translation

Short for Operational Security.

Comment: It would be helpful if there was some more context here

Answer (score 0):

It would be helpful if there was some more context but I would go for 運用{うんよう}セキュリティー.

Comment: *[Operations security (OPSEC)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Operations_security) is a term originating in U.S. military jargon, as a process that identifies critical information to determine if friendly actions can be observed by enemy intelligence, determines if information obtained by adversaries could be interpreted to be useful to them, and then executes selected measures that eliminate or reduce adversary exploitation of friendly critical information.*

Comment: Then it would seem as though my answer is largely irrelevant...